# Converting string in the form of 20100502 to date format in R

Tags: r, date

How to convert a string such as `20100502` into date format `%m/%d/%Y`

I tried to convert using

```
as.Date(20100502, origin="1970-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But, the result is `"57003-04-23"` instead of `05/02/2010`

Comment: You need to convert the string to a `Date` object and then back to a string with a different format. In the first step you have to specify the format of the input string (not the one you want eventually): `x<-as.Date("20100502", format = "%Y%m%d")`. Then with `format` you specify the output format: `format(x,format="%m/%d/%Y")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `as.Date` and `format`

```
format(as.Date("20100502", format = "%Y%m%d"), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "05/02/2010"
```

The `format` argument in `as.Date` refers to the format in which you provide your data to the function. Then in the function `format` you provide the format that you desire.

---

from `?as.Date`

> as.Date will accept numeric data (the number of days since an epoch), but only if origin is supplied.

A workaround as suggested by @Wimpel in comments is to wrap `x` in `as.character`.

```
X$new_Date <- format(as.Date(as.character(X$Date), format = "%Y%m%d"), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code to call X$Date from my .csv file that has multiple dates. But, I am getting an error   'origin' must be supplied. When I supply with 
origin = lubridate::origin, I am getting the result as "04-24-57003".

Comment: @GN Can you add the output of `dput(head(X$Date))` at the end of your question?

Comment: @GN `X$Date` has to be character-format. If not, make it so using `as.character()`.

Comment: Sure, it's c(20100502L, 20100502L, 20100502L, 20100502L, 20100502L, 20100502L

Answer (score 0):

If you already know regular expressions then that provides a very generalisable way of manipulating string variables:

```
date <- "20100502"
gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\2/\\3/\\1", date)
#[1] "05/02/2010"
```